# Restrict text area max length to 100 in React

Tags: html, reactjs, text, textarea, maxlength

```html
<textarea
  className="form-control round InputActive textarea"
  id="txtarea-dwip-service-description"
  name="ServiceDescription"
  value={model.ServiceDescription}
  onChange={event => this.changeHandler(event)}
/>;
```

How to restrict text area length to 100 chars in react.

Answer (score 2):

You should allow value updating but not directly, as you want to add a restriction to it. So:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('')

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const shouldSetValue = value.length < 100

  if (shouldSetValue) setValue(event.target.value)
}

<textarea
  className="form-control round InputActive textarea"
  id="txtarea-dwip-service-description"
  name="ServiceDescription"
  value={model.ServiceDescription}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>;
```

Comment: Downvoting since this solution is much more complicated than `maxLength`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `event` is the new value and `this.changeHandler` is the state updater, you could do something like this:

```js
 <textarea
    maxLength={10}
    className="form-control round InputActive textarea"
    id="txtarea-dwip-service-description"
    name="ServiceDescription"
    onChange={event => this.changeHandler(event)}
    value={model.ServiceDescription} />
```

This will cap the `<textarea>` character limit to 100 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSX maxLength property as maxLength="100"

Comment: Seems to be ignored for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
                            <textarea maxLength={100} className="form-control round InputActive textarea" id="txtarea-dwip-service-description"
                                name="ServiceDescription" value={model.ServiceDescription} onChange={(event) => this.changeHandler(event)} 
                                ></textarea>
```

We have to specify attribute like maxLength={100}, then it worked.

Comment: maxLength is ignored for me